# Passively providing a method for a terminally ill person to commit suicide

Tags: halacha, choleh-sick, suicide

I've read through various posts about suicide and assisted suicide, and I don't believe I've seen this question. If a person has been diagnosed with a terminal illness, or they are in horrific pain (as they describe it), and they have specifically asked for a bottle of sleeping pills or some other medication that can be lethal in large doses, would it be permitted to leave the pills next to the person's bedside and let them decide whether to take the pills or not?

I found a podcast on the subject at "Halacha Headlines", hosted by Dovid Lichtenstein:

["Self-assisted suicide in Halacha and other contemporary medical Shailos"](https://halachaheadlines.com/episodes/self-assisted-suicide-in-halacha-and-other-contemporary-medical-shailos/)

SPEAKERS: Rabbi Yaakov Feitman, Rabbi Yehuda Leib Weiner

Comment: https://ygolan.org/article-category/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%95%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A2/

Comment: It might depend on your level of certainty that they plan on committing suicide... Giving someone the means to do an Aveira is prohibited